# Laravel 6 Fully Custom Auth system

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I'm starting to build an application via Laravel and I'm a beginner.
I want to build a own Auth system, because the current one doesn't suite my use case very well.

My users will login via username and password. Registration dont exists, because all user accounts will be managed by myself.

My problem with the Laravel implementation is that I have slightly different than the Laravel version. My Users table for example won't have timestamps. I tried to build onto the shipped version with the help of the documentation but I failed.

Another problem is that I also want to use `@auth` in the blade syntax with my own implementation.

Is there an Interface for saying that the User is logged in like?:

```php
if(Hash::make("password") === $user->password){
Auth::login();
}else{
return redirect("/login");
}
```

The `Auth::login()` would be the interface to tell laravel that the user is logged in.

(sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is so much of an answer, but not a great comment either so...

> My Users table for example won't have timestamps.

Why? Is there a specific reason? Laravel will manage all of that for you; there really isn't much to do -- kind of a nice little bonus if later on you need to show "Last Login" or "When did this user get created?"

If you want to remove them, you'll want to look at your migrations. Specifically, the `create_users_table` migration. You can find that here:

```
/database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php
```

The date may be different, but that's the file you should look for. In that file you should see something like this:

```
...
$table->rememberToken();
$table->timestamps();  // remove or comment this line out.
...
```

That is the line that creates the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns in your database.

Once you have that line commented out, you can re-run your migration(s) to update your database: `php artisan migrate:refresh`. At that point, you should no longer see the timestamp columns.

You *may* need to update some of the controller logic as well. I've always just left them in there so I can't confidently say you're good to go.

**Blade**

When working with blade, you can check for the current user like this:

```
Auth::user()
```

For example, I could have something like this on my home page:

```
<h1>Hello, {{ Auth::user()->name }}</h1> // Hello, Damon
```

Another option if you need to check if a user is logged in or not you could use `@guest`.

Example:

```
@guest
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
    </li>
@else
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('logout') }}">{{ __('Logout') }}</a>
    </li>
@endguest
```

Here we're checking if the user is authenticated. If they are a guest, show the login link. Otherwise show a logout link.

At a controller level, you can check for the current user like this:

```
// Get the authenticated user
$user = auth()->user();
```

A very simple example could be something like:

**MyController.php**

```
public function example() {
    // Get the authenticated user.
    $user = auth()->user();

    // Redirect if not logged in.
    if($user) {
        return view('my-view');
    } else {
        return redirect('login');
    }
}
```

The [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication) do a great job walking you through setting things up. You can really mold the auth to be however you'd like.

I don't believe I've really answered your question, but hopefully helped give some insight or things to consider.

Comment: When I change the migration, the Auth system gets an exception. I changed "name" to "username" and it cant find "name". Where do I have to change it too?

Comment: [Try this](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication) and look for "Username Customization"

Comment: Could you explain "Manually Authenticating Users" to me? How do I authenticate an user? If I add this function to the LoginController (generated via artisan), then the function wont be called? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Nvm I created my own /login post route and put it there, now its working

Comment: There is a section in the link that is called, "Username Customization". It talks about how you could rename the `username` field to whatever you'd like. Sounds like you're rolling now.